# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - How to set and pass values in variables in pipeline with Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

With Azure Release Pipeline, in a task using the PowerShell Script, I am able to set values of variables and pass to next task using the command

```
Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=varResourceExists;isOutput=true;something'
```

However, when I put this similar command in a task that uses Azure PowerShell, this command is no longer allowed, the task produces a warning:

> 2019-10-22T00:23:14.3080614Z ##[warning]'##vso[task.setvariable
>   variable=varResourceExists;isOutput=true;something' contains logging
>   command keyword '##vso', but it's not a legal command. Please see the
>   list of accepted commands:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296

As a result, the variable varResourceExists cannot be set by my task. I have also tried a conventional PowerShell set value by doing

```
$varResourceExists = 'something'; # this also does not work
```

Is there a way I can set this value in Azure Powershell script so that the next task can reference it?

Answer (score 3):

`##vso[task.setvariable variable=varResourceExists;isOutput=true;something` is not correct syntax. You're missing a closing `]`.

It should be `##vso[task.setvariable variable=varResourceExists;isOutput=true;]something`

Comment: Thank you, a big 'duh' on my part. Now that I can set the variable, and I can confirm I can read the variable varResourceExists in the next task, I am facing a related challenge: I don't seem to be able to put this variable as a custom condition in the task Control Option. I have tried all kinds of syntax, including using 'Reference' from previous task or, reference as an Env variable, it is still not evaluating. Here is my condition: `eq(variables.POWER1_VARRESOURCEEXISTS, 'something')` or `eq(variables.varResourceExists, 'something')`. Both equate to false, I will post the print screen below

Comment: Here is the evaluation for both of the above custom condition: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jfg_xC2C4op6e2sIhO3sS9hgpROMX-Kq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have just solved this, for other's benefit, the correct syntax for referencing my output variable from previous task is: `eq(variables['power1.varResourceExists'], 'something')` - power1 is a reference set in the Output Variables of the previous task

Comment: @HT1 That's great you fixed it. You can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Comment for anonymous user: If you are using this in `inline` script, use `"` instead of `'` viz., `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewVar;]$MyVar"`  as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498719/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my topic. In the pipeline Azure PowerShell task, I can have code such as `Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=varResourceExists;isOutput=true;]False';`

In the Output Variable option, I set a Reference Name "step1":
[Output Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYGEq.png)
Then in the next step, I can do a conditional check using a Custom Condition:
[Custom Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPQFe.png)

I can also reference the variable in my code such as `Write-Host "The step1.varResourceExists says: $(step1.varResourceExists)";`