# Pass variable value from one Powershell script in AZ Powershell task to another script in the next AZ Powershell task in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline that I am experimenting with. The first task in the release pipeline is an AZ Powershell task. This task has a Powershell Script file. The below is the content of the file -

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
   $MyVar
)
$MyVar = "My Value"
Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewVar;]$MyVar'
```

The second task in the pipeline again is an AZ Powershell task with a Powershell script with the below content -

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
   $MyNewVar
)

$MyNewVar = "$(NewVar)"
Write-Host $MyNewVar
```

I run the simple release pipeline and I receive the below error

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NewVar'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Please note that the same works fine when running the same Powershell code Inline in each of the AZ Powershell tasks.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that I do not want to use Inline Powershell. It has to be a .ps1 file located in my DevOps repository.

Answer (score 1):

I added a new argument as below in the second task -

```
-$MyNewVar "$(NewVar)"
```

This as well didn't work successfully but then in the first task, I changed the last line containing single quotes to double, i.e.

```
Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewVar;]$MyVar'
```

changes to

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewVar;]$MyVar"
```

This finally resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use inline script you can't use the syntax `$MyNewVar = "$(NewVar)"`, the `$()` syntax it's for Azure DevOps tasks, PS not recognize it.

You should use the environment variable syntax:

```
$MyNewVar = "$env:NewVar"
```